# WCF Callback: Is it interoperable with Java?

Tags: wcf, web-services, interop, wsdl, callback

Currently I implement all my webservices in the "normal" fashion... that is, I create a WSDL file in Eclipse and then use WSCF.blue (A visual studio extension) to auto-generate the necessary code and it is reply/request. However I was hoping to use callbacks instead, so I can have my services become "push" services.

Before I jump into reworking my application, I was wondering about its interoperability. If I use callbacks (WCF), can my Java client still use this?

Oh, and I guess I should really ask... is it interoperable with more than Java as well? Just in case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `WSDualHttpBinding` and `CompositeDuplexBindingElement` are not interoperable with [Java](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/arungupta/archive/2007/08/wshttpdualbindi.html).

**Edit:**

As pointed by @x0n the original blog post referenced in my answer is not 100% correct. There is a [newer blog](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/haroldcarr/archive/2009/04/metro_interoper.html) post describing the way how to achieve interoperability. As I understand it the approach is similar to using service with asynchronous response correlated through WS-Addressing (WCF doesn't support this exchange model in normal processing). `WsDualHttpBinding` uses some additional features like WS-ReliableMessaging and it also makes the service stateful.

I'm not sure if the described approach will work in all cases because it still talks about one-way messages but duplex communication in WCF can use both one-way and two-way message exchange patterns in both service and callback contracts.

Comment: So Java only supports the request/reply then? Or is there another way?

Comment: Duplex communication is MS extension. It is way to corelate calls between two web services which is build into .NET Framework.

Comment: Reviving an old question here, but actually, the wsdualhttpbinding _binding_ is compatible with java stack (i've tested metro,) but the callbackcontract part is not (the declaration on the servicecontract.) A subtle difference. You can use that binding, but on the java side you have to dig out the ws-addressing replyto header with a message handler and act on it.